# Web server (Hypnotoad - Mojolicious) just vanishing from memory

Tags: perl

Sometimes Hypnotoad proccess just vanishing from memory, so nobody to serve requests. Nothing strange in it's logs.
Is there a way to trace life of Hypnotoad?